# Check if image exists and if not select another one with php

Tags: php, mysql, image, algorithm

I want to display an image with **php**.

How can I check if it exists and if not, *link to another one?*

This is what i've got:

```
<img class="MyClass" src="Images/<?php echo $image1?>.png">
```

So if **image1** doesn't exist it should link to **image2**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First i need to know are you saving image files without extention. If so see the code below

```
$filename = 'Images/'.$image1.'.png';

 if (file_exists($filename)) {
echo '<img class="MyClass" src="Images/<?php echo $image1;?>.png">';
} 
else {
 echo '<img class="MyClass" src="Images/<?php echo $image2;?>.png">';;
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

there are some way but this is the way that I use:

[php documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.is-readable.php)

```
<?php
  $filename="images/".$image_name;
  if(is_readable($filename)){
     $fileToShow=$filename;
  }else{
    $fileToShow="images/default.jpg";
  }
    echo '<img class="MyClass" src="<?php  echo $fileToShow; ?>"/>';
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
<?php
  $file_name="images/".$image_name;
  if(file_exists($file_name))
  {
     $path=$file_name;
  }
  else
  {
    $path="images/default.jpg";
  }
    echo '<img class="MyClass" src="<?php  echo $path; ?>"/>';
?>
```

Comment: It check from user database ie file name only. There is no check in your condition for 404 response.